# Using golang couchbase community sdk with MutateIn

Tags: go, couchbase

When I'm using MutateIn function I always get "No access." error

```
func (s *service) UserUpdateAvatar(avatarLink string) error {
    key := "profile::1"
    var user User
    _, _ = s.profileBucket.Get(key, &user)
    logrus.Println(user) // printing the user as expected
    logrus.Println(avatarLink) // printing the avatarLink as expected
    mtinb := s.profileBucket.MutateIn(key, 0, 0).Upsert("avatarUrl", avatarLink, true)
    _, err := mtinb.Execute() // throughs "No access." error
    if err != nil {
        logrus.Println(err)
    }
    return nil
}
```

I'm using go version 1.6, couchbase community 4.0.0

Answer (score 0):

The `MutateIn` functionality will only work on Couchbase Server 4.5 or later. Some pre-release builds of 4.5 may also contain such functionality (aka "subdoc")